# How to edit a file to add contents in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, tor

I am trying to run this code:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

When this is entered into the terminal, it says `Permission denied...`

I found it [here](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en), it is a guide for installing Tor.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Please precede your command with `sudo` and give your password when requested.

Answer (score 1):

The source you provided states that:

> You need to add the following entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or a new
>   file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`:
>
> deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org utopic main
>   deb-src http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org utopic main

Which means you'll have to open the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file in a text editor to add the changes. You will also need to prefix the command with `sudo` which will run the command as the root user which has full read and write permissions for your system.

From a terminal session run `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` to open the file with the nano text editor, then add the following lines to the file (making sure to change `utopic` for your version of Ubuntu):

```
deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org utopic main  
deb-src http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org utopic main
```

Then press <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file.

Comment: If you're 1000% noob, gedit may serve you better